# Alternative for bignum for primary key in ruby sequel

Tags: ruby, sequel

Since sequel 4.xx this code:

```
Sequel.migration do
  up do
    create_table :rate do
      primary_key :id, :type => Bignum
      ...    
      end  
  end
...
end
```

throws an error 
`Sequel::Error: Unsupported ruby class used as database type: Bignum`
So, what is the alternative if I want to create PK using big integer?
I use ruby 2.2 and postgresql 9.5.

Comment: Let Sequel, based on its knowledge of the database, determine what to use for the primary key. Have you run into problems with its choice or are you trying to outsmart it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Bignum` (the class) as a generic type was removed as it would break in ruby 2.4 as `Bignum` is `Integer` in ruby 2.4.  Use `:Bignum` (the symbol) instead for a generic 64-bit integer type.